# CGO compilation error: invalid flag in go:cgo_ldflag: -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup

Tags: go, cgo, linker-flags

In the past, this call worked fine to compile a 32 bit version of my app for Windows (using cygwin/mingw). Now I get an error:

```bash
    CGO_CFLAGS="-I/Users/Volker/src/includes/third-party/
    -I/Users/Volker/src/includes/C/util/include "
    CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/Users/Volker/src/includes/third-party/ -lmyApp -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup"
    GOPATH=c:/Users/Volker/src/includes/go GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1
    go build -ldflags "-X main.version=2.0.0-7098 -H=windowsgui" -o myApp.exe
```

(Note: I added linebreaks to for better readability. It is all in one line and a single call.)

Error:

```
    go.company.com/myApp: invalid flag in go:cgo_ldflag: -Wl,--enable-stdcall-fixup
```

The thing is, that if I remove the linker flags it complains about, it complains, too:

```
    C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _ElementEventProc_cgo by linking to _Elemen
    tEventProc_cgo@16
    Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
    Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
    C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning: resolving _SciterHostCallback_cgo by linking to _Scit
    erHostCallback_cgo@8
```

So it is wrong if set and wrong if not set?

The only thing that has changed is the go version. I upgraded from 1.13 to 1.21.

Comment: I would say you have some problem with how the symbols which the linker reports in its warnings are declared. If we look in [the docs on `ld`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/binutils-common/ld.1.en.html#enable~5), well'll see that the `--enable-stdcall-fixups` option is supposed to compensate for the mismatch between how the target functions to be linked into are declared and compiled (that is, I _think_ they are compiled as stdcall but declared w/o this calling convention). So, is there any chance to fix the root cause?

Comment: [More background info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Comment: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C) to understand those `@N` in the names referred to in the `ld(1)` manual page.